# How to turn on the Security boot for MS Win10

Tags: windows, uefi

I need to turn on this mode for test of my new drivers.

My operations:

1. In bios I set a support of UEFI
2. Enable the option Security boot.
3. Reboot PC
4. Load msinfo32 and see

   - BIOS is in UEFI
   - Security boot is in off. Why?????

My OS is MS Win 10 x64 1703,
Videocard is Gigabyte Geforce GTX 650, the utility GPU-Z shows that card supports UEFI.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Need to set  Platform Key in the BIOS. Thanks Alex for help.

Answer (score -1):

Check the system summary, look for "BIOS MODE". It might be in legacy mode. (BIOS MODE)

Comment: I wrote BIOS MODE was UEFI

Comment: It might happen that you deleted your Platform Key in your BIOS. Check it, there should be a keys database/record section. And maybe there is a restore platform key option. When you do that windows will be booted in secure boot mode.

Comment: Thanks Alex, you were  right - I didn't  have that key in BIOS. After its setting I got full Security Boot.